# R Linear Regression Data in Single Column

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have the following data as an example:

```
InputName  InputValue Output
===================================
Oxide        35        0.4
Oxide        35.2      0.42
Oxide        34.6      0.38
Oxide        35.9      0.46
CD           0.5       0.42
CD           0.48      0.4
CD           0.56      0.429
```

I want to do a linear regression of `InputValue` vs. `Output` treating different `InputName` as independent predictors.

If I want to use `lm(Output ~ Oxide + CD)` in R, it assumes a separate column for each predictor. In the example above that would mean making a separate column for `Oxide` and `CD`.  I can do that using `cast` function from `plyr` package which might introduce `NA`s in the data.

However, is there a way to direct tell `lm` function that the input predictors are grouped according to the column `InputName`, and the values are given in the column `Inputvalue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are describing a form of dummy variable coding.  This is not necessary in R at all, since any factor column in your data will automatically be dummy coded for you.

Recreate your data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
InputName  InputValue Output
Oxide        35        0.4
Oxide        35.2      0.42
Oxide        34.6      0.38
Oxide        35.9      0.46
CD           0.5       0.42
CD           0.48      0.4
CD           0.56      0.429
", header=TRUE)
```

Now build the model you described, but drop the intercept to make things a little bit more explicit:

```
fit <- lm(Output ~ InputValue + InputName - 1, dat)
summary(fit)

Call:
lm(formula = Output ~ InputValue + InputName - 1, data = dat)

Residuals:
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7 
-0.003885  0.003412  0.001519 -0.001046  0.004513 -0.014216  0.009703 

Coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
InputValue      0.063512   0.009864   6.439  0.00299 ** 
InputNameCD     0.383731   0.007385  51.962 8.21e-07 ***
InputNameOxide -1.819018   0.346998  -5.242  0.00633 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.009311 on 4 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9997,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9995 
F-statistic:  4662 on 3 and 4 DF,  p-value: 1.533e-07
```

Notice how all of your factor levels for InputName appear in the output, giving you a separate estimate of the effect of each level.

Concisely, the information you need are in these two lines:

```
InputNameCD     0.383731   0.007385  51.962 8.21e-07 ***
InputNameOxide -1.819018   0.346998  -5.242  0.00633 **
```

Comment: Hello Andrie, Thanks for the response. However, in your solution above I see "InputValue" as one of the independent variables in addition to InputNameCD and InputNameOxide.  Is that correct? I have only 2 independent variables, (Input)Oxide and (Input)CD. why does it show a third independent variable "(Input)Value" ?

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an interaction term between InputValue and InputVariable to have 2 slopes.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 ways of doing this, `split` the data and do the regressions separately, or use interaction terms to specify that you want to consider the different levels of InputName to have separate slopes:

*Split*

```
lapply(split(dat,dat$InputName),lm,formula=Output~InputValue)
$CD

Call:
FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[1L]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   InputValue  
     0.2554       0.3135  


$Oxide

Call:
FUN(formula = ..1, data = X[[2L]])

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   InputValue  
   -1.78468      0.06254
```

*Interaction*

```
lm(Output~InputName + InputName:InputValue - 1,dat)

Call:
lm(formula = Output ~ InputName + InputName:InputValue - 1, data = dat)

Coefficients:
              InputNameCD             InputNameOxide     InputNameCD:InputValue  InputNameOxide:InputValue  
                  0.25542                   -1.78468                    0.31346                    0.06254
```

For comparision purposes I've also removed the intercept. Note that the estimated coefficients are the same in each case.